# java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused while using spring boot container apis from local

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am getting error while hitting spring boot api. which is internally calling elastic search implementation

```
943a3f6186c9        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0   '/tini -- /usr/local…' ' 11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       127.0.0.1:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   es01
202627ecb7fd        docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0                 '/usr/local/bin/dumb…'   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       127.0.0.1:5601->5601/tcp             kib01
79395c04a8cf        backend:latest                                        '/bin/sh -c '/usr/bi…'   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       127.0.0.1:8083->8083/tcp             bac01
```

docker-compose.yml looks like :

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  bac01:
    image: backend:latest
    container_name: bac01
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8083:8083
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local


networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Elastic Search host : localhost:9200 working fine
kibana host : localhost:5601 working fine

while accessing spring boot apis. which internally uses elastic search rest high level client implementation fails

Error :

```
2020-06-24 10:04:36.154  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.d.backend.common.CommonApplication     : Starting CommonApplication v0.0.1 on 79395c04a8cf with PID 1 (/backend.jar started by root in /)
2020-06-24 10:04:36.198  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.d.backend.common.CommonApplication     : The following profiles are active: docker
2020-06-24 10:04:52.560  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2020-06-24 10:04:52.915  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-24 10:04:52.916  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2020-06-24 10:04:53.962  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-24 10:04:53.963  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16725 ms
2020-06-24 10:05:02.290  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-06-24 10:05:03.322  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8083 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-24 10:05:03.377  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.d.backend.common.CommonApplication     : Started CommonApplication in 33.48 seconds (JVM running for 37.713)
2020-06-24 10:06:53.178  INFO 1 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-24 10:06:53.233  INFO 1 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-24 10:06:53.965  INFO 1 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 722 ms
2020-06-24 10:07:00.732 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at in.device.backend.common.elasticsearch.service.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.save(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:80) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at in.device.backend.common.persistance.service.impl.ESResultServiceImpl.save(ESResultServiceImpl.java:29) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at in.device.backend.common.controller.PerformanceController.getMeta(PerformanceController.java:69) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at in.device.backend.common.controller.PerformanceController.pushSuitResults(PerformanceController.java:48) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few errors -

1. bac01 container is dependent on es01 and kib01. So, add to bac01 -

   ```
    depends_on:
       - es01
       - kib01
   ```
2. kib01 container is dependent on es01. So, add depends_on for es01 in kib01 definition
3. bac01 container won't be able to access es01 using localhost:9200. Since, localhost refers to the container itself(bac01). Access es01 using http://es01:9200

Comment: this was the exact answer i was looking for. worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting multiple Docker containers in a network. In this network you address the cotainers via their name like `containername:5601` instead of `localhost:5601` or `127.0.0.1:5601`. You could make use of a properties file and environment variables to habe different configutations to run your project local or in docker.